# dotnetnuke: can we create a master page?

Tags: dotnetnuke

Can we create a content managed master page in dotnetnuke?

eg. I want the right pane and bottom pane to be content managed, but to show the same thing across all pages.

Thanks

Comment: you might want to ask this on the DNN forums: http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Forums/tabid/795/Default.aspx

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you are describing is essentially what DNN calls a **Skin**.

A DNN skin is actually just an ASP.NET user control (`ascx`) that dictates page-wide or site-wide look and feel, which offers developers the same functionality as a Master page, except that it ties into DNN-specific elements and uses some DNN-specific user controls, such as menu/navigation, logo, breadcrumbs, login/user account links, etc.

Now, in order to add the ability to provide content management capabilities site-wide, you specify an area in your skin to place a module (let's say, a Text/HTML module).  This area is called a **pane**.  Once you add a module to this pane, in its settings you can tell it to appear on every page.  This way, the module can be edited on any page, and its changes will be reflected on all pages automatically.

Check out DNN's site, as it contains a TON of documentation on how to do many common tasks:  http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Support/Documentation/DownloadableFiles/tabid/478/Default.aspx.  Under the **Technical Documentation** section, you'll want to grab the **Skinning** document (I believe it's a PDF).

Comment: I would comment that if you are going to add content on all pages it should be part of the skin - unless of course its something like news or rss feeds that changes all the time

Comment: That would probably depend on if you need the flexibility to have multiple skins with a global module...

Answer (score 1):

DNN Modules can be set to appear on all pages by checking a checkbox in the module settings.  However DNN does not use the concept of a Master Page.  It injects modules (user controls) in containers on a single aspx page at runtime.

A Master Page would be a great addition to DotNetNuke you cannot replace content in a single area of the page.  The whole page refreshes. For example if you have a menu and you only want the content of what you select to appear in a specific content area without refreshing the rest of the page you have to resort to third party modules that attempt to do that but usually fail.  There are 'module wrappers' but all the ones I've tested have issues with modules that allow the user to edit content.  Edit screens are usualy different user control files (ascx) that are launched when you edit the module content.  Since the page refreshes with the new page you have lost your place.   Those module wrappers work fine for static content and some other controls but not for all controls.

IFrames can be used (DNN has one) to trade out content but that doesn't get rid of the probelms mentione above.  I'm heavily invested in DNN, running the UCanUse.com web site so this isn't a slam on DNN.  I just thought I'd try to answer the quesiton with detail.